# Removing firebase-generated id of user saved in database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I save a user in my firebase db I do it via this path:

```
/allUsers/serviceUsers/${usersUID}
```

However, firebase adds another apparent UID to this UID. 
Is there anyway to prevent this or tell firebase to not do it?

[image]

The first ID after serviceUsers is the ID I care about. The second one is generated by firebase and is making working with these objects in the app more painful. I would like that the user object be directly nested under the ID after serviceUsers. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call :

```
firebase.database().ref("/allUsers/serviceUsers/${uid}").setValue(user)
```

Instead of :

```
firebase.database().ref("/allUsers/serviceUsers/${uid}").pus‌​h(user)
```

The push function generate an automatic id.

Comment: Thank you!! However the method is called set and not setValue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a regular POST to

```
/allUsers/serviceUsers/
```

and return the ID? The path parameter should only be used on an update, read, or delete, if you are adhering to REST.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_Web_services

Comment: But I am doing a regular post like so `firebase.database().ref("/allUsers/serviceUsers/${uid}").push(user)`

Pushing to a UID makes it afterwards more easier to retrieve.